# Git merge from Eclipse: Select a ref for merge

Tags: git, eclipse, github

In Eclipse when I created a new branch and tried to merge that to the main branch I got the below pop up.
What is exact meaning of these two entries? I tried to use both and the changes are merged as well when viewed the Git repository via web browser so not very clear of the pop up message. Here "**July**" is the newly created branch. I went to history tab while selecting the main branch and right clicked it and selected merge and got this pop up.

[image]

Comment: In your local `July` branch, are there one or more commits that have not yet pushed?

Comment: @howlger, no. I re ran the scenario one more time. The change was pushed to repository and it is reflecting on remote (checked from web browser) . Then I am trying to merge it from Eclipse

Comment: What do you mean by _"selecting the main branch"_? The last commit of the main branch? Which branch is checked out when doing this? Which JGit/EGit version do you have?

Comment: I meant by saying "selecting the main branch" is switching to main branch which has the last commit. Main branch is checked out. EGit version is 5.10.0.202012080955-r